# Add filled circles (markers) at SwiftUI path points

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw a line with markers at each point by using a Shape view in SwiftUI. I want the line to have a filled circle at each `CGPoint` on the line. The closest to this that I've gotten is by adding an arc at each point. Instead of using the arc, how can I add a `Circle()` shape at each point? I'm open to other approaches to accomplish this. My only requirements are to use SwiftUI and have the ability to interact with the markers.

[image: line plot]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LineShape: Shape {
    
    let values: [Double]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let xStep = rect.width / CGFloat(values.count - 1)
        
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: (1 - values[0]) * Double(rect.height)))
        
        for i in 1..<values.count {
            let pt = CGPoint(x: Double(i) * Double(xStep), y: (1 - values[i]) * Double(rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: pt)
            path.addArc(center: pt, radius: 8, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360), clockwise: false)
        }
        
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LineShape(values: [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5])
            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2.0)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a `Shape` in another `Shape`, but you can combine `Shapes` and `Paths` in a [`Canvas`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/canvas). See [this tutorial](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part5/).

Comment: Canvas doesn't allow interactivity. Is there another option? Maybe two views: one view for the line and another view for the markers that overlay the line.

Comment: You need to have array of points, then you can draw lines path in one shape and circles using `position`
 modifier wrapped all in `ZStack` (in such case you'll have some coordinate space for all shapes/views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make two different shapes, one for the line and one for the markers, and overlay them. Then you can also control their coloring individually:

[image]

```
struct LineShape: Shape {
    
    let values: [Double]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let xStep = rect.width / CGFloat(values.count - 1)
        
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: (1 - values[0]) * Double(rect.height)))
        
        for i in 1..<values.count {
            let pt = CGPoint(x: Double(i) * Double(xStep), y: (1 - values[i]) * Double(rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: pt)
        }
        
        return path
    }
}

struct MarkersShape: Shape {
    
    let values: [Double]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let xStep = rect.width / CGFloat(values.count - 1)
        
        var path = Path()
        
        for i in 1..<values.count {
            let pt = CGPoint(x: Double(i) * Double(xStep), y: (1 - values[i]) * Double(rect.height))
            path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: pt.x - 8, y: pt.y - 8, width: 16, height: 16))
        }
        
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        LineShape(values: [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5])
            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2.0)
            .overlay(
                MarkersShape(values: [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5])
                    .fill(.blue)
            )
            .frame(width: 350, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no marker at the start of the line. Also, you loop through the points twice which doesn't seem efficient, especially for larger arrays. You could add the ellipse in the LineShape.

Comment: you didn't have a marker at point 0 neither – thought you wanted this. If you add the ellipses in the same shape, you can't control their filling, color, etc.  ... and finally this is an answer to your question, not a fully optimized code.

Comment: to get the first point too, just exchange `for i in 1..<values.count` with  `for i in 0..<values.count`

Answer (score 0):

According to previous posts and comments here is my solution:

First there is need to use extension for filling and setting shape stroke:

```
extension Shape {
    public func fill<Shape: ShapeStyle>(_ fillContent: Shape, strokeColor: Color, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.fill(fillContent)
            self.stroke(strokeColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is Scaler struct used to make scaling calculations:

```
struct Scaler {
    let bounds: CGPoint
    let maxVal: Double
    let minVal: Double
    let valuesCount: Int
    
    var xFactor: CGFloat {
        valuesCount < 2 ? bounds.x : bounds.x / CGFloat(valuesCount - 1)
    }
    
    var yFactor: CGFloat {
        bounds.y / maxVal
    }
}
```

Now it's time for real chart shape drawing:

```
struct ChartLineDotsShape: Shape {
    let values: [Double]
    let dotRadius: CGFloat
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard let maxVal = values.max(), let minVal = values.min() else { return Path() }
        let scaler = Scaler(bounds: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height), maxVal: maxVal, minVal: minVal, valuesCount: values.count)
        return Path { path in
            var valuesIterator = values.makeIterator()
            
            let dx = scaler.xFactor
            var x = 0.0
            guard let y = valuesIterator.next() else { return }
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: calculate(y, scaler: scaler)))
            
            draw(point: CGPoint(x: x, y: calculate(y, scaler: scaler)), on: &path)
            x += dx
            
            while let y = valuesIterator.next() {
                draw(point: CGPoint(x: x, y: calculate(y, scaler: scaler)), on: &path)
                x += dx
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func calculate(_ value: CGFloat, scaler: Scaler) -> CGFloat {
        scaler.bounds.y - value * scaler.yFactor
    }
    
    private func draw(point: CGPoint, on path: inout Path) {
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
        path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: point.x - dotRadius * 0.5, y: point.y - dotRadius * 0.5, width: dotRadius, height: dotRadius))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
    }
}
```

If there is single iteration loop lines dots drawing shape we can try to use it in some view:

```
public struct ChartView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        ChartLineDotsShape(values: [0.3, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.5, 2.0], dotRadius: 4.0)
            .fill(Color.blue, strokeColor: Color.blue, lineWidth: 1.0)
            .shadow(color: Color.blue, radius: 2.0, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            .frame(width: 320.0, height: 200.0)
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.1))
            .clipped()
    }
}
```

Finally preview setup:

```
struct ChartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChartView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

and viola:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With charts you can now use `.symbol(.circle)`